# Texturing a crooked object

Tags: modeling, texturing

How would I go about applying texture to an object with a crooked edge?

I'm trying to make a hallway with oldschool style doorways (curvy archway-like doorways), and I'm making the doorframe as a object by itself. So I want the wall to cover up so there is not going to be any holes. But doing that, I have to make the walls crooked around the doorframe to cover up the curvy frame. When I try to apply texture to this, the texture isn't straight but looks very weird. So how would I go about applying texture to this? Or should I model it in a different way? In that case, which other way should I model it?

[image]

Comment: What kind of texture are you trying to apply? (image texture or procedural texture?). Can you post a screen shot of the "weird" result you are getting?

Comment: It's just an image texture. I can post an example, But I don't have the project file with right now.

Image: http://imgur.com/a/LzGgs

Comment: This will happen if you have a square UV map but non-square geometry. Study up on UV mapping and I think you'll find all your answers.

Comment: Can you me a bit more specific? What should I look for?

Comment: This happens when you create the UV and deform the geometry afterwards. You need to unwrap again.

Comment: With the example image (with the bricks) I changed the object, THEN unwrapped it.